# Getting data from Online Db

Tags: android, database

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", user.name));
    return null;
}
```

my activity was unable to import NameValuePair data model thats why i was getting this issue, i think i have not imported the proper library for this function.

Comment: what is your question ?can u explain it more specificity

Comment: i have resolved this issue now. there were some libraries missing . but still for you i was saying that <NameValuePair> was highlighted in red and compiler was showing error and not running the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE can't find a class with name "NameValuePair".

It seems that there is an [Interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes/org.apache.http.NameValuePair.html)
 which is deprecated for API levels 22 and higher.

So, as suggested in the [Preview (Behavior Changes) for Android M](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) you should work with 'HttpURLConnection' or

> declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```